# How to handle order of multiple resolutions of futures?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, meteor, future

I have a future function that looks as follows, where `this._executing.set()` sets a value in a database collection:

```
Cylon._send = function (command) {
  let future = new Future();
  this._executing.set(true);
  // ... waits for an "okay" on `commands` socket before resolving.
  future.resolve(() => this._executing.set(false));
  return future;
}.future();
```

I have another method that makes use of two of these.

```
Cylon.executeSubroutine = function (subroutine, expression) {
  let execFuture = new Future();
  let commandFuture = this._send(`XQ#${subroutine}`);
  commandFuture.resolve(() => this._executing.set(true)));
  execFuture.resolve(() => this._executing.set(false));
  // execFuture waits on `expression` on `messages` socket before resolving.
  Future.wait(commandFuture, execFuture);
}
```

When I log the state, it does the following.

```
executing set to true
executing set to true
executing set to false
executing set to false
```

Why does it do this? I imagine the callbacks are set in an improper order, but I am not sure of how to do this appropriately.